# Google Assistant Interactive Canvas using Angular

Tags: angular, canvas, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have read in the AoG Documentation about creating interactive canvas in Angular.
I tried to create a canvas action using Angular. I have imported the interactive canvas script tag in index.html but i am not sure how to use the interactive canvas in app.component.ts file. When i try to use the interactive canvas in app.component.ts file i am getting a ts error like

```
cannot find name interactive canvas
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Canvas</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/api/interactive_canvas.min.js"></script>

  <!-- SCENE CONTROLLER -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.css']
})
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {
  canvas;

  constructor() {
    this.canvas = interactiveCanvas;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Do i need to install any plugins for it?. Does anyone has tried to create an interactive canvas with Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the documentation you can see one note

```
Note: The interactive canvas object is attached to the window object. If you are using a front-end framework to develop your web app, you need to ensure that you have access to a window to set up the API.
```

Steps did find out the interactive canvas

After adding the interactive canvas script tag just run the angular application and in-browser console just type **window.interactiveCanvas** which displays output

So based on the above approach i have made some few tweaks in the code as well as installed JQuery like below which makes the angular application works in Interactive canvas

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.css']
})
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {
  interactiveCanvas;
  callbacks: any = {};

  constructor() {
    this.interactiveCanvas = (window as any).interactiveCanvas;
    this.callbacks.onUpdate = (data: any) => {
      this.callbacks.html_data = data;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeScenes();
  }

  initializeScenes = () => {
    this.interactiveCanvas.getHeaderHeightPx().then((height: any) => {
      $(document.body).css('margin-top', `${height}px`);
      this.interactiveCanvas.ready(this.callbacks);
    });
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="welcome">
    <p>Angular canvas</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i got the initial output of the canvas like below

[image]